# node_xslt for Transformation.

Tags: node.js, xslt

I am using node_xslt for Transformation. Readme for library tells that I should have libxslt and  libxml2. Where should I place these libraries? I am getting the transformations to  work for simple cases,but not for complicated cases (when I use saxon transformation). 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank You.

Comment: what is your environment? Window/Mac/Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node_xslt` is a C/C++ extension so it should be compiled during installation with the libraries available on your system. If the compilation fails, then you have this libraries missing (which is highly unlikely on the modern OS).

Update:

What I've just did on my Mac (OS X, 10.9.3):

```
$ npm install node_xslt

... big output here
```

Then I've created three files:

*test.js*

```
var xslt = require('node_xslt');                                              
var stylesheet = xslt.readXsltFile('./test.xsl');                             
var document = xslt.readXmlFile('./test.xml');                                                                                                            
console.log(xslt.transform(stylesheet, document, [ ]));
```

and two files from this page: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765388(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And then run the test.js:

```
$ node test.js
```

and it prints the transformation result successfully.

Comment: Even I thought so. But in https://www.npmjs.org/package/node_xslt readme libxslt, libxml2 are listed as requirements. Doesn't that mean I have to install those ? Ppl have commented that once they installed those, they got stuffs working. So where should I place those libraries and how to link them to main program. I am using a MAC.